# WordPress - CPT Page Not Opening in Admin DashBoard

Tags: php, wordpress

I have create **CPT** called **Claim** in WordPress.

It display list of all CPT in its admin panel,but when i'm going to open any specific Post it doesn't open and goes to **500 page** but all others CPT that i have is working perfectly just this CPT (Claim) is not working.

I have search all about this but not getting anything.

Please see attachment, when i open any post of type claim it goes to this page.

List of All CPT(Claim)

[image]

When open any specific post type page

[image]

Can anyone help me??

Thanks

Comment: Try with update permalinks

Comment: Yes..i have done it so many times but still not.

Comment: On register CPT you have rewrite declaration like this `'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'custom-post-type'),`

Comment: I also have added this but not working........previously 2 or 3 days ago its working but now not..

Comment: Try before update permalinks delete all content from .htaccess

Comment: Maybe this article [link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/) help to you